# DB2, get all rows with 1/100 of a column

Tags: db2

I have these rows in my product table:

```
product_name | product_code | percentage. 
prod1@00X    |  1           |    50
prod2@00X    |  2           |    20  
prod3@00X    |  3           |    30
```

I wanna select all the elements of my table but I wanna show 1/100 of the percentage

The result should be:

```
prod1@00X    |  1           |    0.50
prod2@00X    |  2           |    0.20  
prod3@00X    |  3           |    0.30
```

How can I do? 
I wanna find another solution not this:

```
SELECT product_name, product_code, (percentage/100) as percentage FROM product
```

Note: I have several columns in my table, not only product_name | product_code | percentage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT (percentage/100) as percentage,*
FROM product
```

**OR**

Using another alias:

```
SELECT *,(percentage/100) as NewPercentage
FROM product
```

Comment: I thought of this solution, but I have many columns in my table.

Comment: if you want use - select id , (percentage/100) from 
select * from 
then use iner join between two views

Comment: @Raging Bull, I liked the solution, but when I executed it, I get an error :(

Comment: @lolita: What error you are getting? Did you try the second solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use select statement as

```
SELECT *
      , (percentage/100) as newpercentage 
FROM product
where (your condition )
```

Comment: you can , select id , (percentage/100) from 
select * from 
then use iner join between two views